# Pandas remove lambdas when using apply method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Within a pandas pipeline, the best way I know to create a new column row-wise, given a dataframe `df` would be like:

```
(df
 . (...)
 .assign(new_col = lambda df_: df_.apply(lambda row: my_function(row), axis=1)
)
```

assign requires a `pd.Series`, that is itself built row-wise through `apply`.
I feel like this strategy is too verbose (two lambda within a single line of code). Is there a simpler and/or more efficient way to reach the same result?
I am thinking about a syntax similar to:

```
 .assign(new_col = lambda row: my_function(row), axis=1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Both lambdas may be redundant. Please show *my_function*.

Comment: `.assign(new_col = lambda df_: df_.apply(my_function, axis=1))` is a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) accepts a function. Applying `lambda row: my_function(row)` to each row is an obfuscated way of applying `my_function` to each row, as `lambda` is just an anonymous function. Therefore, just feed `my_function` directly:

```
df.(...)\
  .assign(new_col=lambda df_: df_.apply(my_function, axis=1))
```

Note your logic can be simplified if the columns used in `my_function` are unchanged *and* your dataframe index is maintained throughout the prior logic:

```
df.(...)\
  .assign(new_col=df.apply(my_function, axis=1))
```